# Accessing variables indirectly

Tags: javascript, indirection

Within my code (javascript in a firefox extension), i have a list of some 
variables, like this:

```
var myApp = {
 var1: true,
 var2: false,
 var3: true,
 var4: false
};
```

I want to access these variables to get their value indirectly using 
a function:

```
var myApp = {
 var1: true,
 var2: false,
 var3: true,
 var4: false,

 varGetter: function(aName) {
  // code
  return myApp.aName.value;
 }
};
```

I call this function like this for example:

```
if(myApp.varGetter("var2")) {alert("true")};
```

Now, how this function can be implemented to do what i want?

Comment: Note: you don't have a list of variables, you have _one_ variable that references an object with several properties. Regarding your `varGetter()` method, what should it do if asked for the value of a property that doesn't exist, e.g., `myApp.varGetter("fred")`?

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
The relevant code knows always what to ask but i want this to be 
done indirectly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to access a property with the dot notation and the variable.

```
myApp.aName.value;
```

this sometimes creates new property or returns `undefined`

You should use this notation instead

```
myApp[aName];
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Making some tests in Scratchpad, your suggestion seems to work :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `myApp[aName]` to use a variable as a property name:

```
var myApp = {
 var1: true,
 var2: false,
 var3: true,
 var4: false,

 varGetter: function(aName) {
  return myApp[aName];
 }
};

console.log(myApp.varGetter("var1")); // true
```

Also, to avoid hardcoding `myApp` in your function you can replace it with `this[aName]`.

Answer (score 0):

You can access gloval variables via the window variable.
Example:

```
var foo = 'asdf';
alert(window['foo']);
```

To get json variables, use the same notation:

```
var myApp = {
 var1: true,
 var2: false,
 var3: true,
 var4: false
};

function varGetter(name) {
    return myApp[name];
}
```

EDIT: Misread the question.

Comment: That's not JSON, it's just an object.

Comment: @nnnnnn You're right. I usually think of it js objects as JSON, because the notation is similar.

Answer (score 0):

If what you want to do is encapsulation (keeping variables private), you should use the **module pattern**, which would give you that :

```
var myApp = (function(){
    //you can't access those variable doing myApp.var1 for example
    var data = {};
    data.var1 = true;
    data.var2 = false;
    data.var3 = true;
    data.var4 = false;

    //then explicitly make your getter/setter
    function varGetter(varName){
        return data[varName];
    }

    //finally, return an object into myApp, out of this closure
    return {
        varGetter : varGetter
    };
})()
```

Comment: 404 topheman not found.

Comment: yeah Xero, I'll wait a little before answering an other question, just to enjoy that :D